# How to ignore non-letters from std::cin

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I am trying to read a string from cin, then loop through the string to count which characters in that string are actually *letters* in the English alphabet. I have wrote a program that works just fine, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this, without looping through the entire English alphabet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string my_str; //will use to store user input
    getline(cin, my_str); //read in user input to my_str

     int countOfLetters = 0; //begine count at 0
     string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz"; //the entire english alphabet

     for(int i = 0; i < my_str.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++){
            if (tolower(my_str.at(i)) == alphabet.at(j)){ //tolower() function used to convert all characters from user inputted string to lower case
                    countOfLetters += 1;
            }
        }
     }

     cout << countOfLetters;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is my new and improved code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string my_str; //will use to store user input
    getline(cin, my_str); //read in user input to my_str

     int countOfLetters = 0; //begine count at 0
     string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz"; //the entire english alphabet

     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < my_str.length(); i++){
            if (isalpha(my_str.at(i))){ //tolower() function used to convert all characters from user inputted string to lower case
                    countOfLetters += 1;
            }
        }


     cout << countOfLetters;
    return 0;
}
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/):

```
for(int i = 0; i < my_str.length(); i++)
    if (isalpha(my_str.at(i))
        countOfLetters++;
```

Comment: Well Alex, you were first, so I guess you get the rep! Thanks for the short and sweet answer. I have updated my OP with my fancy new code.

Comment: @AdamJ Please note that I was focusing on _"without looping through the entire English alphabet"_. If you are interested in making the entire loop shorter and in a C++ style, check the answer of **@0x499602D2**.

Answer (score 2):

Use [isalpha()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) to see which characters are letters and exclude them.

So, you could modify your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string my_str;
  getline(cin, my_str);

  int countOfLetters = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < my_str.length(); i++) { // int i produced a warning
    if (isalpha(my_str.at(i))) {  // if current character is letter
      ++countOfLetters;           // increase counter by one
    }
  }

  cout << countOfLetters;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std::count_if()` algorithm along with the iterator interface to count characters for which some predicate returns true. The predicate can use `std::isalpha()` to check for alphabetical characters. For example:

```
auto count = std::count_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str),
                           [&] (unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
```

Comment: Can't you pass `std::isalpha` directly as the predicate?  Why wrap it in a lambda?

Comment: @BenVoigt There's another overload in `<locale>` that takes a template argument and a separate `std::locale` instance but I didn't want to use a cast to select the correct one.

Comment: Avoiding the overload mayhem is a fair enough reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if the int cast is between 65-90 or 97-122

at example

```
(int)'a'
```

Should give 97

This will be the most performant method without any doubt.
Its better than using isalpha().

Check http://www.asciitable.com/ for ASCI Numbers

Comment: Definitely use `'A'` rather than a magic number 65... and whether it actually is faster than `isalpha` may surprise you.

Comment: He wants to check if the leter is in Alphabet so if((int)letter > 64 && (int)letter < 91) 
it is in the alphabet, easiest and most performant check :o

Comment: This is more meaningful and gets the same code: `letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'`  But then you need to check two cases, by then a lookup table is becoming competitive.

Comment: It does, but in this case he wouldnt probably know what happens in the Background, which can lead to problems if he uses this method a other way

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha` works well for this particular problem, but there's a more general solution if the list of characters to accept wasn't so simple. For example if you wanted to add some punctuation.

```
std::set<char> good_chars;
good_chars.insert('a'); good_chars.insert('A');
good_chars.insert('b'); good_chars.insert('B');
// ...
good_chars.insert('z'); good_chars.insert('Z');
good_chars.insert('_');
// the above could be simplified by looping through a string of course

for(int i = 0; i < my_str.length(); i++){
    countOfLetters += good_chars.count(my_str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Until you go to full unicode, a simple lookup table (like almost all implementations of `isalpha` use) is far faster and lower overhead than `std::set`, and just as flexible.